# partial-domain permutation and strong assumption

Tags: one-way-function, chosen-ciphertext-attack, oaep

Quoting "[Verified Security of Redundancy-Free Encryption
from Rabin and RSA](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/308.pdf)", Chapter 2 (on page 4):

> OAEP was proved IND-CCA-secure by Fujisaki et al. [28] under the assumption that the underlying trapdoor permutation is partial-domain one-way. This is in general a stronger assumption than just one-wayness, but fortunately both assumptions are equivalent in particular for RSA.

- What is exactly are full-domain (and partial-domain) one way permutations?
- Which is the stronger assumption?
- Which is it more secure or efficient?

Comment: Did you read the cited paper on OAEP? I would expect that it's likely to have a definition of those terms.

Comment: D.W., by the way, did u refer the original OAEP paper by Bellare&Rogaway? Please be specific, thanks